# How to improve add() method in arraylist class

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, enums

I have a:

main class, 
sport class, 
sportList class 
and supplies enum class where variables look like this paired with shipping costs: BAT ("Bat", 13.99), Helmut ("Helmut", 4.99)...

As the user enters more supplies in the main class they are added to the arrayList (sportsList class) via add() method (these are basically gear objects to be shipped out) - if the arrayList is empty the gear is added...thereon in if the gear is added further the arrayList is searched for a duplicate of the same gear and when found the price of the gear is added to the existing value of the gear, which includes a shipping value that should only be added once per gear object.

This works ...but as I'm new to java, I wanted to see how this could be improved?
Thanks all!

```
public void add (Sport sport) {

if (sportList.size() == 0){
        sportList.add(sport);
        sportList.get(0).addShipValue(sport.supplies.getCost());


    }else{
        for (int index = 0; index <sportList.size() ; index++) {

            if (sportList.get(index).supplies.getName().equals(sport.supplies.getName())) {
                sportList.get(index).addShipValue(sport.getShipValue());

             break;

            }
            if(index == sportList.size() - 1) {
                sportList.add(sport);
                sportList.get(index + 1).addShipValue(sport.supplies.getCost());

                break;
            } 


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the right collection. You should instead use a `Map<String, Sport>`, where the key is the name of the supplies of the sport, and the value is the sport itself.

```
private Map<String, Sport> sportsByName = new HashMap<>();

public void add (Sport sport) {
    sportsByName.merge(sport.supplies.getName(),
                       sport,
                       (oldSport, newSport) -> {
                           oldSport.addShipValue(newSport.getShipValue);
                           return oldSport;
                       }); 
}
```

A HashMap lookup by key isO(1). Putting a new value in a HashMap is O(1), too.

Comment: I'm restricted to having to use arraylist for this however